# PowerShell: Output of Regular Expression instead of Result

Tags: regex, string, powershell, extract

Ok, long time visitor, first time post.

Instead of PowerShell telling me the result of my Regular Expression is "True" or "False", instead I would like the string. I know there are other ways to do this and I already have a working version, but I would like to use Regular Expressions to "extract" the string.

For example:

```
$ipconfig = ipconfig | select-string "IPv4" | select-object -first 1
$ipconfig -match "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b"
```

Just returns "True", instead I would like the IP address.

Is there a way of accomplishing this using regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've already got it, just need to check a variable you get for free:

```
$ipconfig = ipconfig | select-string "IPv4" | select-object -first 1
if ($ipconfig -match "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b") { 
    $matches[0]
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the .NET object:

```
$ipconfig = ipconfig | select-string "IPv4" | select-object -first 1
([regex]"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b").matches($ipconfig) | % { $_.value }
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Using -replace:

```
 $ipconfig = ipconfig | select-string "IPv4" | select-object -first 1 
 $ipconfig -replace '.*\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b.*','$1'
```